# How do I distinguish between the two of these elements using Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, enzyme

I have the following two blocks of code generated from React Material UI both contained within a larger React element written by myself.

```
<InputAdornment muiFormControl={{...}} position="end" classes={{...}} component="div" disablePointerEvents={false} disableTypography={false}>
    <div className="MuiInputAdornment-root-35 MuiInputAdornment-positionEnd-38 Hook-searchFieldInputAdornmentStyle-1adbbdv">
        <pure(SearchIcon)>
            <SearchIcon>
                <WithStyles(SvgIcon)>
                    <SvgIcon classes={{...}} color="inherit" component="svg" fontSize="default" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <svg className="MuiSvgIcon-root-40" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" color={[undefined]} aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
                            <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z" />
                            <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" />
                        </svg>
                    </SvgIcon>
                </WithStyles(SvgIcon)>
            </SearchIcon>
        </pure(SearchIcon)>
    </div>
</InputAdornment>
```

and

```
<InputAdornment muiFormControl={{...}} position="end" classes={{...}} component="div" disablePointerEvents={false} disableTypography={false}>
    <div className="MuiInputAdornment-root-35 MuiInputAdornment-positionEnd-38">
        <pure(ExpandLessIcon)>
            <ExpandLessIcon>
                <WithStyles(SvgIcon)>
                    <SvgIcon classes={{...}} color="inherit" component="svg" fontSize="default" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <svg className="MuiSvgIcon-root-40" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" color={[undefined]} aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
                            <path d="M12 8l-6 6 1.41 1.41L12 10.83l4.59 4.58L18 14z" />
                            <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" />
                        </svg>
                    </SvgIcon>
                </WithStyles(SvgIcon)>
            </ExpandLessIcon>
        </pure(ExpandLessIcon)>
    </div>
</InputAdornment>
```

The only important difference is that one has a **`SearchIcon`** contained in it and the other has an **`ExpandLessIcon`**

I want to find the one with the **`SearchIcon`** using Enzyme. I have the following so far

> ```
> wrapper.find(InputAdornment).containsNode(SearchIcon)
> ```
>
> but it gives me the following error

ReferenceError: `SearchIcon` is not defined

I should add that `SearchIcon` is not a component of mine and is dynamically generated by material-ui so I can't reference its type.

Any idea how I should adjust my enzyme query  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.containsNode()` needs a React Element like `<div />`, not React Component like `div`.

You can use a displayName in `find`, e.g. to get the `SearchIcon` element:

```
expect(wrapper.find(InputAdornment).find('SearchIcon')).toHaveLength(1)
```

or the `InputAdornment` containing `SearchIcon`:

```
expect(
  wrapper.find(InputAdornment).filterWhere(x => x.find('SearchIcon').exists())
).toHaveLength(1)
```

Comment: Thanks. Howevever this returns the ```SearchIcon``` component and not the ```InputAdornment``` which contains a ```SearchIcon```

Comment: yes, of course it does. feel free to save the intermediate element, e.g. `const input = wrapper.find(InputAdornment); expect(input.find('SearchIcon')).toHaveLength(1);`

Comment: Yes I know but that's still going to involve some sort of loop I'd imagine., My issue is that I have potentially lots of ```InputAdornment``` elements and I need an easy way to to filter out the one which has ```SearchIcon```. I thought something like this may work but it doesnt. ```wrapper.find(InputAdornment).filterWhere(item => item.find("SearchIcon"));```

Comment: I see, updated answer, `filterWhere` needs a boolean instead of a wrapper => [.exists()](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/exists.html)

Comment: A slight shorter variation of your answer also works - ```wrapper.find(InputAdornment).filterWhere(x => x.exists('SearchIcon'))``` x